# getSupportedCipherSuites vs getDefaultCipherSuites Apache CXF

Tags: java, ssl, cxf

This question is for people who know the working of Apache CXF JAX RS. When the CXF creates an HttpsUrlConnection it puts a wrapper around the default SSLSocketFactory which is called SSLSocketFactoryWrapper, which has a parameter called ciphers.

This parameter is initialized by calling getSupportedCipherSuites() of SSLContextImpl.

But when default implementation of JAVA creates an SSLSocket, it initializes the ciphers by calling getDefaultCipherSuites() which returns a smaller list of ciphers.

getSupportedCipherSuites() returns the list of ciphers which are enabled 
+ those which could be enabled.

Looks like my program is failing just because CXF calls getSupportedCipherSuites rather than getDefaultCipherSuites. Any body know why this is the case? Is there any way to override this behavior. I know about setting CipherSuiteFilter which I can use to reduce the number of ciphers but it is not easy to use it in my environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default SSLSocketFactory instead via:

tlsClientParameters.isUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory()

(see here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/tls-configuration.html#TLSConfiguration-ClientTLSParameters)

I don't know why your program would fail just because a wider range of cipher suites are installed as opposed to the default...

Colm.

Comment: It might fail a security audit due to using an insecure cipher suite. It's very poor practice on whoever's part this is.

Comment: What I learned about SSL Handshaking is that the client presents a list of Cipher suites and the server chooses one of them...If this is the case it would not matter that some of the cipher suites in the list are insecure right? Those can be ignored by the server. Also figured out that this problem happens to me with JAVA 8 only, Apparently JAVA 8 has added more cipher suites in its default list.

Comment: @Colm Yes I know about this option. It works that way. But it is more of a fallback implementation, as it means that we are not using cxf's capabilities.

Comment: And if it helps, I am getting a SocketException :Connection Reset as the exception.

Comment: @EJP - the insecure cipher suites are explicitly filtered out.